How can I select all rows from two SQLite tables, but prefer one if there are matching rows in both?
I have two tables, each with a round and an id column and additional data columns. One table is the planned version, the other one is the actual one. E.g.:
planned:
round | id | value
------+----+------
    1 |  1 |     a
------+----+------
    2 |  1 |     d
------+----+------
    2 |  2 |     e

actual:
round | id | value
------+----+------
    1 |  1 |     a
------+----+------
    1 |  2 |     b
------+----+------
    2 |  1 |     c

Now I want to select all data, but if such a dataset (identified by round and id) is present both in the planned and in the actual table, I want to use the actual value. Additionally, all planned values not present in the actual table should be selected.
In this example, I'd like to get:
round | id | value
------+----+------
    1 |  1 |     a    (present in both, but identical)
------+----+------
    1 |  2 |     b    ("actual" values, not present in "planned")
------+----+------
    2 |  1 |     c    ("actual" values, different from "planned")
------+----+------
    2 |  2 |     e    ("planned" values, not present in "actual")

Edit: I found a way to select this using two UNIONed queries, one with a subquery:
SELECT round, id, value FROM actual
UNION
SELECT round, id, value FROM planned
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TRUE FROM actual
    WHERE actual.round = planned.round
    AND actual.id = planned.id
)
ORDER BY round, id

but this seems to be a bit clumsy … is there a more elegant way?

@nbk Maybe I'm missing the forest for the trees, but I really don't get how adding a consecutive number helps me here?

I think you're looking for an outer join and the coalesce() (or its SQLite equivalent).

Here is the FULL OUTER JOIN solution with COALESCE() that mustaccio alluded to:
SELECT
    COALESCE(actual.round, planned.round) AS round,
    COALESCE(actual.id, planned.id) AS id,
    COALESCE(actual.value, planned.value) AS value
FROM actual
FULL JOIN planned
    ON actual.round = planned.round
    AND actual.id = planned.id

Probably the simplest solution syntactically but again, might not necessarily be the most performant.

Thanks a lot for this additional solution! I'll try to measure which one is faster.

@TobiasLeupold No problem! Cheers!

Per what nbk said, if you UNION ALL the two tables together, you can then use a window function like ROW_NUMBER() to enumerate all of the rows and prioritize the ones that exist in the actual table, like so:
SELECT round, id, value
FROM
(
    SELECT round, id, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY round, id ORDER BY SourceTableSortId) AS FilterId
    FROM
    (
        SELECT round, id, value, 1 AS SourceTableSortId
        FROM actual

        UNION ALL

        SELECT round, id, value, 2 AS SourceTableSortId
        FROM planned
    ) AS AllRows
) AS Sorted
WHERE FilterId = 1

This will prioritize the rows from the actual table by sorting on SourceTableSortId within the ROW_NUMBER() function's enumeration, when the same row (by round and id) exist in both tables.

Thanks for the explanation. This works, but it's even more complicated than the solution I found …

@TobiasLeupold No problem! You may want to post your solution for peer review, to ensure there's no potential issues missed and to help other future readers with similar issues.

I did, 27 mins ago ;-)

@TobiasLeupold Btw, you should post solutions as an answer, not an edit to the original post. Also worth noting, sometimes the more complex looking solution is the more performant one in SQL. Not always the case, but typically worth comparing runtimes between multiple solutions, if it matters in your use cases. (If I had to guess though, I think your solution using a correlated subquery will be faster.)
